# jquery ajax form submit is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-post

this is my html form

```
<form id="contactForm1" method="POST" action="downloadfile">
   <input id="tesst" name="tesst" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $val['file_name'];?>"/>
   <div id="download" class="btn btn-danger">Download</div>
</form>
```

And here is the Jquery function

```
var frm = $('#contactForm1');
              frm.submit(function(ev) {
                 $.ajax({
                   type: frm.attr('method'),
                   url: frm.attr('action'),
                   data: frm.serialize(),
                   success: function(data) {
                      alert('ok');
                   }
                  });
                 ev.preventDefault();
              });
```

I don't know much about Jquery.

Please anybody can help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: it misses the `input submit` button / you have to use the click event instead of submit - `frm.submit` to `$('#download').click`

Comment: it also have wrong form action

Comment: @Spokey - thank you. i add a submit button and it works. but i also try the other way. but it didn't post that form.

this is the jquery code 

$('#download').click (function(ev) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: frm.attr('method'),
                            url: frm.attr('action'),
                            data: frm.serialize(),
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert('ok');
                            }
                        });

                        ev.preventDefault();
                    });

Comment: @AwladLiton - if you can tell me the best way to add action="" it will be helpful to me. 

Thank you. 
(don't mind about my wrong English)

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: I didn't quite test it when I wrote it but it seems to work fine > http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/bNa7d/ (not sure if you still added the `var frm`)

Comment: @Felix - i'm using PHP
thanks

Comment: action should be file name with extension like something.php or something.html

Comment: action doesn't require an extension if `.htaccess` is configured for it

Comment: @AwladLiton - actually I'am using codeigniter so thats why i think to redirect it using route.  what is the best thing to do in this situation ?

Comment: @Spokey - yes that jsfiddle example is working well. i'll try again 

if you can put your comment as a answer i can approve it. Thank You Very much for giving your time for me.

Comment: @Spokey - I find that what happend with that 

to use click function thing i had to use this
 $(document).ready(function() {

am I right? now it is also working 

thanks

Comment: If your code is in the `head` then yes. If you put it before you end `body` you won't need that

Comment: @Spokey -  Thank you.. that was the case. my code is in the head section 
learned much more things because of your kindness. 
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve your problem

1. You change your `div` (download button) to a `input submit` button and leave your script as it is
2. You change the function to run when the div is clicked and not when the submit event is fired (the reason is that submit is only fired by a submit button)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/bNa7d/

```
var frm = $('#contactForm1');
$('#download').click(function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things

- You need to add `input` submit element to your form
- Change `action="downloadfile"` to `action="downloadfile.php"` if your `downloadfile.php` is the same directory with your current HTML file.